# Required field validation on Sign Up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using Custom SignUpSignIn Policy, and on our signUp form we have textbox, dropdown and a checkbox which are all required fields.

When a user does not fill in the necessary details,

for the text box, it is highlighted with red line around the text box and as we enter the text box, it says "This information is required." in red color text on top of the text box which is good.

But for the Dropdown and checkbox, a simple message "Missing required element [Country]" is displayed at the top of the form(not even red color text) and no highlighting on the field. User may not even notice that.

How can I achieve the same behavior as the textbox for dropdown and checkbox?

Thanks,

Comment: looks js support is right around the corner.  [source](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br?tracking_code=6ca3e5c24a0cf830fa3a1f96c8ef3001).  "We are planning to roll out .b2clogin.com without JS support sooner and the page contracts will be coming to private preview in the coming weeks."

Comment: @spottedmahn,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Wait** for the ability to use JavaScript via the "shared domain" feature.

[UserVoice item reference](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br).

> ...as a result of ‘shared domains’ this means that you will be able to start using your tenant as a subdomain of a ‘shared domain’, in the form of {tenant name}.b2clogin.com where b2clogin.com is the ‘shared domain’. You will be able to run Javascript when you are running on this shared domain...

---

> I just want a way for all the required field validation messages to display in Red ...

That you can achieve with [custom CSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) which you can do today.

> But for the Dropdown and checkbox, ... , is displayed at the top of the form

Moving stuff around would require JavaScript.

Comment: can't we achieve this using out of the box functionality? and if the javascript ability becomes available, are you suggesting to write our own validation message? If we can just display the error message text in Red color that would be enough for me.

Comment: Any more thoughts please. I just want a want for all the required field validation messages display in Red same like the out of the box TextBox functionality. We have multi lingual messages to be displayed, so really looking for some out of the box ability to handle this.  Thanks,

Comment: we have the ability to use Javascript in private preview now, can you please let me know if there is any place I can find the documentation regarding Javascript? We are building custom SignUp/SignIn policies, and we need to support multilingual